# Answer incorrectly flagged as poor quality

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review

I found the [linked answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/28372/1549) by @TFD in the "Low Quality Posts" review queue. The text up top says, *"This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content."*

I don't see anything wrong with either the length or the content of the post. On the contrary it is far above average quality (in my subjective appraisal).

Maybe the "Low Quality Post" selection code throws in the odd random post to keep us on our toes. More likely it's a bug though.

Comment: The thing that does the flagging is one-or-more heuristics that cannot attempt to understand or judge the answer itself. It simply applies the pattern of what *looks to the algorithm* to be low quality. Inevitably, there will be some false-positives and some false-negatives. The system *does* also throw in audits ("to keep us on our toes"), but: it always tells you afterwards.

Comment: This was an old post, though, so I don't think it was auto-VLQ. I've only seen that on new posts.

Comment: I saw that same answer while clearing my review queues. WTF?? I clicked "Looks OK" and didn't get any kind of message after, so I assume it was just dumb user error (or intentional ugliness).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you see a good post in the Low Quality review queue, simply click "Looks OK".

Posts can be placed in the Low Quality review queue automatically by the system based on various heuristics, or by another user flagging them. It takes more "Looks OK" than "Recommend deletion" votes to remove it from the queue.

Some such reviews are [review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121/189912), automated tests meant to trip up so-called "robo-reviewers" who simply click their way through reviews without actually giving them due consideration. If you run into an audit, you will be told if you passed or failed immediately afterward.

Comment: Fancy that! We are being kept on our toes. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: To be clear, if this wasn't a review audit, it was a human mis-flagging the post, not a bug. There's no reason to think there was a bug; people misuse flags all the time. In particular, people often think that "very low quality" means "super extra downvote, very wrong answer" (nope, it means there's no way to edit and salvage it into a real post, even a wrong one) and "spam" means "nonsense" (nope, it means unsolicited advertisement).

Comment: @Jefromi Wait until you run across a user who upvotes very low quality posts and puts VLQ flags on the highest quality content...

Comment: @MichaelHampton Perhaps it's different on SF. In my experience on Seasoned Advice, benign misuse like I described is much more common than that kind of thing.

Comment: @jefromi in this case it was a human misflagging indeed, we had a moderator flag about it. It was a "Not an answer" flag, so I think that even 10K users wouldn't have seen it. (I always forget which types of flag are visible to high rep users).

Comment: @Jefromi Oh yes, we get plenty of people who think VLQ means "really wrong answer". We don't delete these unless the answer is malicious or otherwise harmful, as even wrong answers can be valuable in their own way.